# Python list manipulation: Add an item to a string element to make it a 2 item list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say in Python I have a list as follows:
`a = ['spam', 'eggs', 100, 1234]`

Now I have the value `devon` and I want to add this to 'spam' to make it a list itself, with the result looking like:
`a = [['spam', 'devon'], 'eggs', 100, 1234]`

**Edit** Drew raises a good question, so I'll expand this:

After `devon`, we also get sent `baloney` and want the result to be
`a = [['spam', 'devon', 'baloney'], 'eggs', 100, 1234]`

What is the simplest way to do this?
Is there a generic way to append items where it is unknown if the element is a string or list beforehand?

Comment: What if the first item of a is a list?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? Maybe `'spam'` should have been `['spam']` in the first place.

Comment: @user2357112, it has to do with data that comes from another system and depending on updates, it is unknown if an element should just be a string or a list until later updates occur. Short answer is yes, I'm sure :)

Comment: Why can't it be a list if there's only 1 string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modify `a[0]`:

```
>>> a = ['spam', 'eggs', 100, 1234]
>>> a[0] = [a[0], 'Devon']
>>> a
[['spam', 'Devon'], 'eggs', 100, 1234]
```

For your updated question:

```
>>> items = ['devon', 'baloney']
>>> a = ['spam', 'eggs', 100, 1234]
>>> a[0] = [a[0]] + items
>>> a
[['spam', 'devon', 'baloney'], 'eggs', 100, 1234]
```

If you're not sure about the position of 'spam' then use a list comprehension:

```
>>> a = ['spam', 'eggs', 100, 1234]
>>> [item if item != 'spam' else [item, 'devon'] for item in a]
[['spam', 'devon'], 'eggs', 100, 1234]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def add_to_first(list, element):
    try:
        list[0].append(element)
    except AttributeError:  # Not a list
        list[0] = [list[0], element]


items_string = ['spam', 'eggs', 100, 1234]
items_list = [['spam'], 'eggs', 100, 1234]

add_to_first(items_string, 'devon')
add_to_first(items_list, 'devon')

print items_string
print items_list
```

I get:

```
>> [['spam', 'devon'], 'eggs', 100, 1234]
>> [['spam', 'devon'], 'eggs', 100, 1234]
```

Comment: Thanks, we probably just going to create a class to handle this data type as we have more complex cases as well. It should be a neat way to tie everything together.